# Can not add box shadow (css)

Tags: html, css

I am making a resume for an assignment. I have pretty much completed everything, but i cant add shadow to skills section as required for some reason, maybe i dont understand how bow-shadow works. Can you please show me how to add shadow like its done in the picture. below im attaching my html and css file and a screenshot for reference

```css
.skills-display {
    width: 50%;
    /* height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black; */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.skill-progress-bar {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 2rem;
    padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.eighty-percent {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;

    background-color: orange;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 7px grey;
}

.skill-name span {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.twenty-percent {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    background-color: #2857a4;
}

.seventy-percent {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    background-color: #20ebb8;
}

.ninety-percent {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(252, 220, 0);
}
```

```html
            <section id="skills">
                <h1 class="section-heading mb75px">
                    <span>
                        <i
                            class="fa-solid fa-chalkboard-user"
                        ></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>SKILLS</span>
                </h1>
                <div class="skills-display">
                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="eighty-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>HTML</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="twenty-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>C++</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="seventy-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>Python</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="ninety-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>JavaScript</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div
                            class="ninety-percent"
                            style="background-color: #43853d"
                        >
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>NodeJS</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="eighty-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>Express</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

**REQUIRED**

[image]

**MINE**

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could just post the parts relative to your question. Not every single line of your code

Comment: Please make a _Minimal, Reproducible Answer_.

Comment: Edited, Please take a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have padding that messes up.
Here is a fixed version, added/removed lines are marked:

```css
.skills-display {
    width: 50%;
    /* height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black; */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.skill-progress-bar {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 2rem;
    
/*    padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px; */ /* removed */
    margin: 10px;                       /* added */
    line-height: 2rem;                 /* added, this will center the content*/
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.eighty-percent {
    width: 80%;
                                       /* removed */
/*    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;*/

    background-color: orange;
}

.skill-name span {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.twenty-percent {
    width: 20%;
                                       /* removed */
/*    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;*/
    background-color: #2857a4;
}

.seventy-percent {
    width: 70%;
                                       /* removed */
/*    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;*/
    background-color: #20ebb8;
}

.ninety-percent {
    width: 90%;
                                       /* removed */
/*    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;*/
    background-color: rgb(252, 220, 0);
}


                                       /* added */
.skill-progress-bar
{
    overflow: hidden; /* this will hide box-shadow from child element on edges that touching it's parent (aka only show it on right side) */
}

.skill-progress-bar,
.skill-progress-bar > div
{
    box-shadow: 1px 0 7px grey;
}
.skill-progress-bar > div
{
    height: 100%;
 /* border-radius: 0.8rem 0px 0px 0.8rem; */  /* this is unnecessary because we are hiding overflow */
}
```

```html
<section id="skills">
                <h1 class="section-heading mb75px">
                    <span>
                        <i
                            class="fa-solid fa-chalkboard-user"
                        ></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>SKILLS</span>
                </h1>
                <div class="skills-display">
                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="eighty-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>HTML</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="twenty-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>C++</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="seventy-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>Python</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="ninety-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>JavaScript</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div
                            class="ninety-percent"
                            style="background-color: #43853d"
                        >
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>NodeJS</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="eighty-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>Express</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were adding the shadow on the percentage but it should be on the progress-bar itself (parent container to the variable percentage), if needed. I fixed some of the issues and added comments over the changes made.
Also,removed box-shadow from eighty percent as it made it look uglier and if needed you should add it on the progress bar

Added a background color for the page to this and this should look exactly like your page. You can check out the changes made below

```css
.skills-display {
    width: 50%;
    /* height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black; */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Made changes here */
.skill-progress-bar {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 2rem;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
   /* border-radius: 0.8rem; */
     border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border:0.8px solid grey;
    /*box-shadow: 0 1px 7px 0  grey;*/
}

.eighty-percent {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;

    background-color: orange;
    /*box-shadow: 1px 0 7px grey;*/
}

/* Added new changes here */
.skill-name{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
height:100%;
}

.skill-name span {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.twenty-percent {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    background-color: #2857a4;
}

.seventy-percent {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    background-color: #20ebb8;
}

.ninety-percent {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(252, 220, 0);
}
```

```html
<section id="skills">
                <h1 class="section-heading mb75px">
                    <span>
                        <i
                            class="fa-solid fa-chalkboard-user"
                        ></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>SKILLS</span>
                </h1>
                <div class="skills-display">
                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="eighty-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>HTML</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="twenty-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>C++</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="seventy-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>Python</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="ninety-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>JavaScript</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div
                            class="ninety-percent"
                            style="background-color: #43853d"
                        >
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>NodeJS</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                        <div class="eighty-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>Express</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the shadow i wrap your bars again. (class new). I commented in my code what is new.

```css
.skills-display {
    width: 50%;
    /* height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black; */  
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center; /* new */
    gap: 20px; /* new */
}

.skill-progress-bar {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 2rem;
    padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    background-color: lightgrey;  
}

.eighty-percent {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    background-color: orange;    
}

.skill-name span {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.twenty-percent {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    background-color: #2857a4;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 7px grey;
}

.seventy-percent {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    background-color: #20ebb8;
}

.ninety-percent {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(252, 220, 0);
}

/* new */
.skills-display {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.section-heading {
  text-align: center;
}

.new {
  background-color: #999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 40px;  
}

.skill-name {
  padding-top:9px;
}
```

```html
<section id="skills">
                <h1 class="section-heading mb75px">
                    <span>
                        <i
                            class="fa-solid fa-chalkboard-user"
                        ></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>SKILLS</span>
                </h1>
                <div class="skills-display">
                  
                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                      <div class="new">
                        <div class="eighty-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>HTML</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                      <div class="new">
                          <div class="twenty-percent">
                              <div class="skill-name">
                                  <span>C++</span>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                      <div class="new">
                        <div class="seventy-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>Python</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                      <div class="new">
                        <div class="ninety-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>JavaScript</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                      <div class="new">
                        <div
                            class="ninety-percent"
                            style="background-color: #43853d"
                        >
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>NodeJS</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="skill-progress-bar">
                      <div class="new">
                        <div class="eighty-percent">
                            <div class="skill-name">
                                <span>Express</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```